# a sequence $\frac19,\frac{7}{17},\frac{17}{25}, \cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have got a sequence $\frac19,\frac{7}{17},\frac{17}{25}, \cdots$ and got two different version for general term:

$$\frac{2n^2-1}{8n+1} \ \ \& \ \  \frac{8(n-1)+(-1)^{n+1}}{8n+1}$$

but uisng the 1st one we get the sequence is divergent and the second one gives us convergence!!

I am really confused!

Comment: the question appeared in one of my exams, so I would write that we can't conclude from finitely many terms?? @AnuragA

Comment: Yes. You can show that fourth terms do not match so these are possibly two different sequences.

Answer (score 2):

These two expressions only agree until $n=3$. At $n=4$, the first expression gives $\frac{31}{33}$, whereas the second gives $\frac{23}{33}$. As $n \to \infty$, these expressions are giving you two different sequences. So one will converge and the other won't but their behaviors don't have to be dependent on each other just because the first few terms are a match.

Comment: When you are given a few terms of a sequence there is no mathematical reason to assume the pattern continues.  The sequence could do anything at all.  We generally expect that the sequence will continue in the "obviously simplest" way and I believe the problem setter has the responsibility to make sure there is one "obviously simplest" way.  OP has demonstrated to my satisfaction that the problem setter has failed.  I think this answer is more responsive to the question than ones that just say the sequence can go anywhere (though they are correct)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, finitely many terms do not tell us about the convergence of the whole sequence.

Also, in general, we can't tell the whole sequence from finitely many terms.

Answer (score 0):

You have made up your formulas based on just three terms. Others may come up with other formulas or just make up other terms for the rest of the sequence.

You only have three terms of your sequence, depending on what happens with other terms everything is possible.

For example you can define the rest of your sequence as $$4,5,6,...n,...$$ to make it divergent or $$ 0,0,0,...$$ or anything else.